# Python drop rows from Dataframe based on RIGHT substring of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to delete rows from it where values end in either xx.x1 or xx.x6.

Please forgive the formatting if it's wrong, this is my first post...

### Existing output:

```
UID    Col1    Col2    Col3
001    abcd    44.05   xyz
002    bcde    56.01   oig
003    cdef    88.00   itr
004    defg    33.76   lkj
005    efgh    22.00   hgf
```

### Desired output:

```
UID    Col1    Col2    Col3
001    abcd    44.05   xyz
003    cdef    88.00   itr
005    efgh    22.00   hgf
```

I can get as far as printing the substring of Col2 that I thought I could use with an operator:

```
df = df.iloc[2].str[-2:]
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Col2
5
1
0
6
0
```

I tried

```
df = df[df.iloc[4].str[-1:] != 1 or 6]
```

but that throws **"ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."**

Suggestions please?

Comment: What is your output of `df['Col2'].dtype`?

Comment: Hi Erfan, output of 'df['Col2'].dtype' is "object". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `isin`:

```
df.loc[~df["Col2"].astype(str).str[-1].isin(["1","6"])]
```

Or with `str.contains`:

```
df.loc[~df["Col2"].astype(str).str.contains("\d{2}.\d[16]")]

   UID  Col1   Col2 Col3
0    1  abcd  44.05  xyz
2    3  cdef  88.00  itr
4    5  efgh  22.00  hgf
```